# Fastest way to perform sparse matrix multiplications in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

BACKGROUND: I am trying to build a real-time drum simulation model, for which I need really fast matrix-vector products. My matrices are of the size ~5000-10000 rows/cols, out of which only 6 entries per row are non-zero, hence I am inclined to use sparse matrices. I am using `scipy.sparse` module. The iterations are as below.

```
Vjk_plus_sparse = Vjk_minus_sparse.transpose()
Vj = Vjk_plus_sparse.dot(constant)
np.put(Vj, Nr, 0.0)
Uj[t] = Uj[t-1] + np.transpose(Vj)/fs
Vj_mat = adj_mat_sparse.multiply(Vj)
Vjk_minus_sparse = Vj_mat-Vjk_plus_sparse.multiply(end_gain)
```

Here, `Vjk_plus_sparse`, `Vjk_minus_sparse` and `Vj_mat` are sparse CSR matrices, `Vj` is a `numpy` array, and `Uj` is a `numpy` matrix where each row represents `Uj(t)`. `end_gain` is an array which is a static `numpy` array for dampening of vibrations.

THE ISSUE: A single iteration takes about 3 ms for `size = 4250`. With the most significant 
steps being the last 2 lines. They together take about 2.5 ms. I would ideally need it to run in `0.1 ms`, which would be more than a 10x speedup. This is the maximum extent of vectorization possible for the problem, and I cannot parallelize as I am marching in time, at least physically it won't be accurate.

ATTEMPTS: I tried fiddling with the sparse data structures, and found best performance with all of them being CSR (Compressed Sparse Row), with the values as quoted above. I also tried to replace the `multiply()` method with a matrix multiplication, by repeating Vj, but that worsened the time, as the resultant operation would be a sparse*dense operation.

How can I speed this up within python itself? I am open to trying c++ as well, though migrating now would be a major pain. Also, since `scipy` is essentially based in c, would it even give that much of a speedup?

**Added a complete runnable example**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.patches
import math
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
import scipy.fftpack as spf
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time

sqrt_3 = 1.73205080757


class Pt:
    def __init__(self,x_0,y_0):
        self.x_0 = x_0
        self.y_0 = y_0
        self.id = -1
        self.neighbours = []
        self.distance = (x_0**2 + y_0**2)**0.5

class Circle:
    def __init__(self,radius,center):
        self.radius = radius
        self.center = center
        self.nodes = []

    def construct_mesh(self, unit):
        queue = [self.center]
        self.center.distance = 0
        curr_id = 0
        delta = [(1.,0.), (1./2, (3**0.5)/2),(-1./2, (3**0.5)/2),(-1.,0.), (-1./2,-(3**0.5)/2), (1./2,- (3**0.5)/2)]
        node_dict = {}
        node_dict[(self.center.x_0,self.center.y_0)] = curr_id
        self.nodes.append(self.center)
        curr_id+=1
        while len(queue)!=0:
            curr_pt = queue[0]
            queue.pop(0)
            # self.nodes.append(curr_pt)
            # curr_id+=1
            for i in delta:

                temp_pt = Pt(curr_pt.x_0 + 2*unit*i[0], curr_pt.y_0 + 2*unit*i[1])
                temp_pt.id = curr_id
                temp_pt.distance = (temp_pt.x_0 ** 2 + temp_pt.y_0 ** 2)**0.5          
                # curr_id+=1
                if (round(temp_pt.x_0,5), round(temp_pt.y_0,5)) not in node_dict and temp_pt.distance <= self.radius:
                    # print(temp_pt.x_0, temp_pt.y_0)
                    self.nodes.append(temp_pt)
                    node_dict[(round(temp_pt.x_0,5), round(temp_pt.y_0,5))] = curr_id
                    curr_id+=1
                    queue.append(temp_pt)
                    curr_pt.neighbours.append(temp_pt.id)

                elif temp_pt.distance <= self.radius:
                    curr_pt.neighbours.append(node_dict[round(temp_pt.x_0,5), round(temp_pt.y_0,5)])

        # print(node_dict)

    def plot_neighbours(self, pt):
        x = []
        y = []
        x.append(pt.x_0)
        y.append(pt.y_0)
        for i in (pt.neighbours):
            x.append(self.nodes[i].x_0)
            y.append(self.nodes[i].y_0)
        plt.scatter(x,y)
        plt.axis('scaled')

    def boundary_node_ids(self):
        boundary_nodes = []
        for j in range(len(self.nodes)):
            if(len(self.nodes[j].neighbours) < 6):
                boundary_nodes.append(j)
        return boundary_nodes

    def add_rim(self, boundary_node_ids, unit):
        c = self.center
        rim_ids = []
        N = len(self.nodes)
        for i in range(len(boundary_node_ids)):
            d = self.nodes[boundary_node_ids[i]].distance
            xp = self.nodes[boundary_node_ids[i]].x_0
            yp = self.nodes[boundary_node_ids[i]].y_0
            xnew = xp + xp*unit/d
            ynew = yp + yp*unit/d
            new_point = Pt(xnew, ynew)
            new_point.id = N + i
            rim_ids.append(N+i)
            self.nodes.append(new_point)
            self.nodes[boundary_node_ids[i]].neighbours.append(new_point.id)
            self.nodes[N+i].neighbours.append(boundary_node_ids[i])
        return rim_ids

def find_nearest_point(mesh, pt):
    distances_from_center = np.zeros(len(mesh.nodes))
    for i in xrange(len(mesh.nodes)):
        distances_from_center[i] = mesh.nodes[i].distance
    target_distance = pt.distance
    closest_point_id = np.argmin(np.abs(distances_from_center-target_distance))
    return closest_point_id

def init_impulse(mesh, impulse,  Vj, poi, roi):
    data = []   
    for i in range(len(Vj)):
        r = ((mesh.nodes[i].x_0 - mesh.nodes[poi].x_0)**2 + (mesh.nodes[i].y_0 - mesh.nodes[poi].y_0)**2)**0.5
        Vj[i] = max(0, impulse*(1. - (r/roi)))
        if i in Nr:
            Vj[i] = 0.
        for k in mesh.nodes[i].neighbours:
            data.append(np.asscalar(Vj[i])/2.)

    return Vj, data


r = 0.1016                                 #Radius of drum head
# rho = 2500                          #Density of drum head
thickness = 0.001                       #Thickness of membrane
# tension = 1500                     #Tension in membrane in N
param = 0.9
c = (param/thickness)**(0.5)    #Speed of wave in string
duration = 0.25
fs = 4000
delta = c/fs

center = Pt(0,0)
point_of_impact = Pt(r/2., 0)
center.id = 0
mesh = Circle(r,center)
mesh.construct_mesh(delta)
N = len(mesh.nodes)

Nb = []
for j in range(N):
    if len(mesh.nodes[j].neighbours) < 6:
        Nb.append(j)

Nr = mesh.add_rim(Nb, delta)

N = len(mesh.nodes)
print(N)

row_ind = []
col_ind = []

for j in range(N):
    for k in mesh.nodes[j].neighbours:
        row_ind.append(j)
        col_ind.append(k)

data = np.ones(len(col_ind))

adj_mat_sparse = sp.csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), shape = (N,N))

Vjk_plus = sp.csr_matrix([N, N])
Vj = np.zeros([N,1])
Uj = np.zeros([int(duration*fs), N])
Vj_mat = sp.csc_matrix([N,N])

closest_point_id = find_nearest_point(mesh, point_of_impact)
Vj, Vjk_data = init_impulse(mesh, -10.0, Vj, closest_point_id, r/10.)
Vjk_minus_sparse = sp.csr_matrix((Vjk_data, (row_ind, col_ind)), shape = (N,N))
constant = (1./3)*np.ones([N,1])


Vjk_plus = Vjk_minus_sparse.transpose()
np.put(Vj, Nr, 0.0)
Uj[1] = Uj[0] + np.transpose(Vj)/fs
Vj_mat = adj_mat_sparse.multiply(Vj)
Vjk_minus_sparse = Vj_mat - Vjk_plus

end_gain = np.ones([N,1])
end_gain[Nr] = 1.0          

for t in range(2,int(duration*fs)): 
    Vjk_plus = Vjk_minus_sparse.transpose()
    Vj = Vjk_plus.dot(constant)
    np.put(Vj, Nr, 0.0)
    Uj[t] = Uj[t-1] + np.transpose(Vj)/fs
    Vj_mat = adj_mat_sparse.multiply(Vj)
    Vjk_minus_sparse = Vj_mat-Vjk_plus.multiply(end_gain)
```

Comment: Please post a complete runnable example.  Please also include dummy data with that (or upload an example of real data somewhere and post a link).  It is necessary to have a working benchmark to improve this.

Comment: How many element multiply-adds are there per matrix multiplication?  What would be the theoretically best possible time based on the. CPU you're running on?  Size = 5k with 6 nonzero elements per row would seem to imply 5k*5k*6 multiply-adds.  2.5ms is a really good timing for this already - almost impossibly good in fact, it takes a lot less than one clock per op.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I realised. I did just one matrix multiplication, and that itself was taking 0.1 ms, so the only way out for me is to somehow reduce the problem size. Unless there is some library out there that does it even faster.